# Drop unnecassary columns after merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def Merge_Name_Not_In_Nex(df_change,nex):
change_copy = df_change.copy()
df2 = change_copy[change_copy['NAMECHANGE'].isna()]
df = df2.merge(nex, how = "left",left_on = 'NAME',right_on = "NAME2", indicator = True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge'] == 'left_only']
Export_df(df,"NEW_TERM.csv")
return df
```

I am trying to merge on the left one and drop all the columns from the right one, but its not doing what I want it to do.

Here is some sample data : 
DF1

```
                              NAME          NAMECHANGE
0      LM_Autopolsterung_Ja       Autosattlerei
1  LM_Motorradpolsterung_Ja   Motorradsattlerei
2  LM_Blumendekorationen_Ja  Blumenarrangements
3         LM_Bodenbeläge_Ja                 NaN
4    LM_Bootspolstereien_Ja      Bootssattlerei
```

DF2

```
                           NAME2                      NAMECHANGE
0      LM_Autopolsterung_Ja             LM_Autosattlerei_Ja
1  LM_Motorradpolsterung_Ja         LM_Motorradsattlerei_Ja
2  LM_Blumendekorationen_Ja        LM_Blumenarrangements_Ja
4    LM_Bootspolstereien_Ja            LM_Bootssattlerei_Ja
5  LM_Dekorationsartikel_Ja  LM_Verkauf von Dekoartikeln_Ja
```

These two get matched. Works well, but afterwards all the following columns from the second dataframe get attached

Comment: could you share some of ur data?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of code that shows how to drop columns you don`t need.

```
del dataframe_name['column_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a dataframe so:

df.drop(columns=['B', 'C'])

From the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html